# How can I append and prepend some text to all files in a folder in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, append, prepend

I have the folder structure like below

`resources/folder1 , /folder2 , /folder3`

Now I want this text to be prepended with newlines:

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
```

and this should appended at the bottom

```
{% endblock %}
```

of all the files in folder and sub-directories under Resources. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change directory to `resources`, create two template files: `BEGIN` and `END`.

#### File: BEGIN

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
```

#### File: END

```
{% endblock %}
```

#### Run commands:

```
sed -i '1s/^/\n/' */*
sed -i -e '1rBEGIN' -e '$rEND' */*
sed -i '1d' */*
```

---

No backslashs escaping any more, this solution is very clear and simple and scales well.

Comment: Thanks buddy that worked. That was very easy and simple to understand. only problem is it give error when there is subdirecory as it tries to apply to that as well

Comment: @Zombie21. Use `*/*.html`  if your files have extensions(`.html`).

Comment: If you want to apply to all files in subdirectories, try `shopt -s globstar`, and use `**/*.html`

Comment: Looks like a great solution but doesn't work for my case... I want to do it in the current directory and only to certain file type.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a myriad ways to do it.  Subject to the file names not containing spaces or the like, then you can use:

```
find resources -type f -print |
while read file
do
    {
    echo "{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}"
    echo "{% block body %}"
    cat $file
    echo "{% endblock %}"
    } > tmp.$$
    cp tmp.$$ $file
    rm -f tmp.$$
done
```

The set of braces performs I/O redirection on the enclosed commands.  They're a little tricky to use accurately on the same line as commands, but the code above is easy.  The redirection to `tmp.$$` is OK if you are not working in a hostile environment; you might need to use `mktemp` or some other command if you think people might be subverting you while you run the script.  The `cp` and `rm` done as shown means that you don't run into problems if any of the files is actually a symlink (or a hard link); the links are preserved.  Alternatives such as `mv tmp.$$ $file` would break links or symlinks.

Comment: This will append the header/footer N times for files that have N links.  But this is fixable, whereas the `sed -i` solution breaks hard links.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @WilliamPursell.  Since this is tagged Linux, the GNU `sed -i` feature is usable in general.  Links and symlinks can often lead to problems.  If multiple-concatenations are an issue, then you'd probably arrange to generate a list of file names plus inode numbers, sort uniquely on (just) the inode number, and then process the corresponding name just once.  But it is more verbose than the `sed -i` (and the accepted `sed -i` could be written without the two auxilliary files).

Comment: `sed -i` is less verbose, but it breaks hard links and uses auxiliary files!

Answer (score 2):

You can make that with `sed` :

```
 sed -i -e "
 1s/^/\n{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}\n{% block body %}\n/ ;
 $s/$/\n{% endblock %}/
 " $(ls -R resources/folder* )
```

Comment: i am getting this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 89: unknown command: `\'`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be in two steps imo:

```
egrep -r -l "{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}" resources/ |xargs sed -i 's/ \{\%\ extends\ \'\:\:layout\.html\.twig\'\ \%\} /\n \{\%\ extends\ \'\:\:layout\.html\.twig\'\ \%\}/g'
```

and then:

```
egrep -r -l "{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}" resources/ |xargs sed '$ a\\n'
```